# Connecting directly to Database in Rails (Heroku?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am currently writing RoR applications and deploying using Heroku.

Is there any way to connect directly to the DB using a connection string?

I guess what I am asking here is can I connect directly to the DB, is there a connection string, how can I get the connection string, etc. I want to be able to perform querys on the DB outside of the terminal I am developing. My current solution is using

```
heroku db:pull 'anotherPOSTGRESQLdatabasesCONNECTIONstring'
```

and then performing queries on that database, but this is not a valid solution, because I am developing this application for users who are not code savvy, and they should be able to perform queries on the database without me or them using the terminal.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this programatically (in the app), or just give access to a database interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be asking is available here:  https://postgres.heroku.com/

Click "Try For Free", Select the option where you already have a heroku account, login with the correct credentials.

Now you can choose the database you want to perform actions on, and create "Data Clips" that your clients can run to get data reports etc (data clips can be used to run arbitrary select SQL commands).

Comment: Thank you nzifnab. Unfortunately this is not the answer I was looking for, as I was already aware of this service and had been using this service with the above method mentioned. When I create a database on postgres.heroku.com, i must pull the DB from my app. This requires me to run a command in terminal before someone else can perform query of their own. The answer I want is, imagine someone using Microsoft Excel is able to perform a select query on my apps database given a connection string, directly. Although this service is provided by Heroku, it is not ideal in my situation.

Comment: Perform a `heroku config` command, there you will see a variable named `DATABASE_URL`. If you use the **Heroku Postgres service** there you can see your username and password too.

Comment: @MoB I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question :(  If the customers are not code savvy, why is it necessary that they be able to perform queries on a database when they probably don't know how to form such queries?  Is this a case of you wanting to let them use something like Navicat to interface with a database on heroku?  Or are you specifically asking how you can get your RoR app to point to the database on heroku?  Do you want this to occur exclusively in production (which it should, automatically), or do you want even the development app to point to the production DB?

Comment: All I wanted was a connection string :P Thanks though guys this is no longer a problem, I ended up abandoning Heroku at this point. Moved to Linode, experienced freedom ever since.